# Images and Fake Data Population - Yields nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to populate data of a db very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792442/generating-paperclip-image-uploads-with-fake-data-ruby-on-rails-populator-fa) thread.

My sample rake looks like this

```
namespace :db do
   desc "Fill database with sample data"
   users_to_create = 1
   dogs_to_create = users_to_create * 1
   breed_array_size = 177 #0 indexed
   array_zips = ["11211", "11215", "01776"]
      task populate: :environment do
         admin = User.create!(name: "First Last",
                     email: "something@gmail.com",
                     password: "somepass",
                     password_confirmation: "somepass",
                     zip_code: "11211",
                     admin: true)

         users_to_create.times do |n|
                    name  = Faker::Name.name
                    email = "example-#{n+1}@example.com"
                    password  = "password123"
                    zip_code2 = array_zips.sample
                         User.create!(name: name,
                              email: email,
                              password: password,
                              zip_code: zip_code2, 
                              password_confirmation: password)
          end

         dogs_to_create.times do |d|
             primary_breed = 

['affenpinscher'],
['afghan_hound'],
['airedale_terrier'],
['akita'],
['alaskan_malamute'],
['american_english_coonhound'],
['american_eskimo_dog'],
['american_foxhound'],
['american_staffordshire_terrier'],
['american_water_spaniel'],
['anatolian_shepherd_dog'],
['australian_cattle_dog'],
['australian_shepherd'],
['australian_terrier'],
['basenji'],
['basset_hound'],
['beagle'],
['bearded_collie'],
['beauceron'],
['bedlington_terrier'],
['belgian_malinois'],
['belgian_sheepdog'],
['belgian_tervuren'],
['bernese_mountain_dog'],
['bichon_frise'],
['black_russian_terrier'],
['black_and_tan_coonhound'],
['bloodhound'],
['bluetick_coonhound'],
['border_collie'],
['border_terrier'],
['borzoi'],
['boston_terrier'],
['bouvier_des_flandres'],
['boxer'],
['boykin_spaniel'],
['briard'],
['brittany'],
['brussels_griffon'],
['bull_terrier'],
['bulldog'],
['bullmastiff'],
['cairn_terrier'],
['canaan_dog'],
['cane_corso'],
['cardigan_welsh_corgi'],
['cavalier_king_charles_spaniel'],
['cesky_terrier'],
['chesapeake_bay_retriever'],
['chihuahua'],
['chinese_crested'],
['chinese_shar-pei'],
['chinook'],
['chow_chow'],
['clumber_spaniel'],
['cocker_spaniel'],
['collie'],
['curly-coated_retriever'],
['dachshund'],
['dalmatian'],
['dandie_dinmont_terrier'],
['doberman_pinscher'],
['dogue_de_bordeaux'],
['english_cocker_spaniel'],
['english_foxhound'],
['english_setter'],
['english_springer_spaniel'],
['english_toy_spaniel'],
['entlebucher_mountain_dog'],
['field_spaniel'],
['finnish_lapphund'],
['finnish_spitz'],
['flat-coated_retriever'],
['french_bulldog'],
['german_pinscher'],
['german_shepherd_dog'],
['german_shorthaired_pointer'],
['german_wirehaired_pointer'],
['giant_schnauzer'],
['glen_of_imaal_terrier'],
['golden_retriever'],
['gordon_setter'],
['great_dane'],
['great_pyrenees'],
['greater_swiss_mountain_dog'],
['greyhound'],
['harrier'],
['havanese'],
['ibizan_hound'],
['icelandic_sheepdog'],
['irish_red_and_white_setter'],
['irish_setter'],
['irish_terrier'],
['irish_water_spaniel'],
['irish_wolfhound'],
['italian_greyhound'],
['japanese_chin'],
['keeshond'],
['kerry_blue_terrier'],
['komondor'],
['kuvasz'],
['labrador_retriever'],
['lakeland_terrier'],
['leonberger'],
['lhasa_apso'],
['lowchen'],
['maltese'],
['manchester_terrier'],
['mastiff'],
['miniature_bull_terrier'],
['miniature_pinscher'],
['miniature_schnauzer'],
['neapolitan_mastiff'],
['newfoundland'],
['norfolk_terrier'],
['norwegian_buhund'],
['norwegian_elkhound'],
['norwegian_lundehund'],
['norwich_terrier'],
['nova_scotia_duck_tolling_retriever'],
['old_english_sheepdog'],
['otterhound'],
['papillon'],
['parson_russell_terrier'],
['pekingese'],
['pembroke_welsh_corgi'],
['petit_basset_griffon_vendeen'],
['pharaoh_hound'],
['plott'],
['pointer'],
['polish_lowland_sheepdog'],
['pomeranian'],
['poodle'],
['portuguese_podengo_pequeno'],
['portuguese_water_dog'],
['pug'],
['puli'],
['pyrenean_shepherd'],
['rat_terrier'],
['redbone_coonhound'],
['rhodesian_ridgeback'],
['rottweiler'],
['russell_terrier'],
['saluki'],
['samoyed'],
['schipperke'],
['scottish_deerhound'],
['scottish_terrier'],
['sealyham_terrier'],
['shetland_sheepdog'],
['shiba_inu'],
['shih_tzu'],
['siberian_husky'],
['silky_terrier'],
['skye_terrier'],
['smooth_fox_terrier'],
['soft_coated_wheaten_terrier'],
['spinone_italiano'],
['st._bernard'],
['staffordshire_bull_terrier'],
['standard_schnauzer'],
['sussex_spaniel'],
['swedish_vallhund'],
['tibetan_mastiff'],
['tibetan_spaniel'],
['tibetan_terrier'],
['toy_fox_terrier'],
['treeing_walker_coonhound'],
['vizsla'],
['weimaraner'],
['welsh_springer_spaniel'],
['welsh_terrier'],
['west_highland_white_terrier'],
['whippet'],
['wire_fox_terrier'],
['wirehaired_pointing_griffon'],
['xoloitzcuintli'],
['yorkshire_terrier']


        user_id = 1
        name = Faker::Name.name
        nick = Faker::Name.name[0..2]
        primarybreed = primary_breed[d].join('')
        secondarybreed = "Purebred"
        age = rand(1..12)
           Dog.create!(user_id: user_id,
              name: name,
              nick: nick,
              age: age,
              primarybreed: primarybreed,
              secondarybreed: secondarybreed
              )
           end
     Dog.all.each { |dog| dog.image=File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root,  "public/images/fake_dogs/#{dog.primarybreed}", '*')).sample); dog.save! }

   end

 end
```

The error I get is

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

it points to

```
 Dog.all.each { |dog| dog.image=File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root,  "public/images/fake_dogs/#{dog.primarybreed}", '*')).sample); dog.save! }
```

If I tried to test with this line:

```
 Dog.all.each { |dog| dog.image=File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root,  "public/images/test/", '*')).sample); dog.save! }
```

and it works (with test folder having a few images), but with the first method, it's breaking. If I comment out this line for test purposes, and create the dog without the image, and then go into rails console.

```
Dog.first.primarybreed
```

returns the breed, so it's not that the breed that is nil, and there ARE images in the (first 20 breed-folders, and I'm just trying to create one dog in this example which would be the first breed, which does have images )

What is nil here?  I've been working on this for a while... maybe losing my mind.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long array, but I didn't want to nix it in case there's a problem there.

Comment: I'd guess that the strings you are supplying are not the issue. I would be curious what the Faker::Name.name looks like. To me this looks like the most obvious nil case but there is also a weird User.create block in the user_to_create.times that I am not quite sure of as well.

Comment: The issue is really only with Dog images created at the end. I've set user_to_create at the top so I can just change variables at the top to avoid going swimming through my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the chat session with OP,

OP had created the folders for `primarybreed` with a `perl` command

```
perl -lne 'mkdir $_' dirnames.txt
```

`dirnames.txt` had a list of `folder` names to be created. There was an extra space in all the folder names listed in `dirnames.txt`

So upon trying to access with `dog.primarybreed`(without a space) in following command

```
 Dog.all.each { |dog| dog.image=File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root,  "public/images/fake_dogs/#{dog.primarybreed}", '*')).sample); dog.save! }
```

**dog.primarybreed(without space)** was not matching the **actual folder name(with space)** which caused

`Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root,  "public/images/fake_dogs/#{dog.primarybreed}", '*'))`

to return an empty array.

When you `sample` an empty array, you get `nil`

```
2.1.0 :001 > [].sample
 => nil
```

Finally, `nil` was passed to `File.open(nil)` which resulted in error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

To fix this issue, all the folders for `primarybreed` were *named correctly* and the *extra character was removed* from name.

Comment: Kirti - Give the link of the chat to the answer too. It is well allowed. Otherwise it is very hard to match the answer with the post.

Comment: Arup.. Answer is self explanatory. I don't think anyone would have any problem understanding or matching the issue or how it was resolved. It's a simple directory name mismatch issue, I simply gave a thorough explanation. Here is the link to chat if anyone is interested   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: @user3317140 sorry XD

Comment: I'm glad this was the issue though, I was driving myself nuts.  I should've picked up on the mismatch earlier.

Comment: No worries, It happens. And Glad to help :)